# Where can I find old global road maps?

Tags: global, historical, map

I am looking for some old global road maps (anytime before 1990 or 2000). Does anyone have any suggestions where I can find such data?

Comment: this answer? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15316/1511 (if not, please edit your question to include more details, e.g. date period, countries, etc)